# How does Python convert bytes into float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have the following code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print(float(b'5'))
```

Which prints `5.0` with no error (on Linux with utf-8 encoding). I'm very surprised that it doesn't give an error since Python is not supposed to know what encoding is used for the bytes object.

Any insight?

Comment: Have you rad the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#encodings)? and https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects

Comment: @Kasramvd: the documentation for `float()` states it accepts a `str`, a number, or a type that implements `__float__`. `bytes` doesn't implement `__float__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) it's mentioned that If the argument is a string, it should contain a decimal number, optionally preceded by a sign, and optionally embedded in whitespace. doesn't `b'5'`  follow that rule? Although it should have been specified clearly in the documentation.

Comment: Fair question, since [not all encodings are supersets of ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6531750/4014959).

Comment: @Kasramvd: no, it doesn't. The `bytes` type is not considered a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, I mean since bytes represent a sequence of characters and they can also contain decimals, it should have been mentioned as well which as you mentioned it's a bug in documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When passed a `bytes` object, `float()` treats the contents of the object as ASCII bytes. That's sufficient here, as the conversion from string to float only accepts ASCII digits and letters, plus `.` and `_` anyway (the only non-ASCII codepoints that would be permitted are whitespace codepoints), and this is analogous to the way `int()` treats `bytes` input.

Under the hood, the implementation does this:

- because the input is not a string, [`PyNumber_Float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Float) is called on the object (for `str` objects the code jumps straight to `PyFloat_FromString`).
- `PyNumber_Float()` checks for a `__float__` method, but if that's not available, it calls [`PyFloat_FromString()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html#c.PyFloat_FromString)
- `PyFloat_FromString()` accepts not only `str` objects, but any [object implementing the buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects). The `String` name is a Python 2 holdover, the Python 3 `str` type is called `Unicode` in the C implementation.
- `bytes` objects implement the buffer protocol, and the [`PyBytes_AS_STRING` macro](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bytes.html#c.PyBytes_AS_STRING) is used to access the internal C buffer holding the bytes.
- A combination of two internal functions named `_Py_string_to_number_with_underscores()` and `float_from_string_inner()` is then used to parse ASCII bytes into a floating point value.

For actual `str` strings, the CPython implementation actually converts any non-ASCII string into a sequence of ASCII bytes by only looking at ASCII codepoints in the input value, and converting any non-ASCII whitespace character to ascii 0x20 spaces, to then use the same `_Py_string_to_number_with_underscores()` / `float_from_string_inner()` combo.

I see this as a bug in the documentation and have [filed issue with the Python project](https://bugs.python.org/issue33567) to have it updated.

Comment: I know there won't be a thing about python that this guy doesn't know.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So, just to be clear, this will fail with certain encodings, such as UTF-16?

Comment: @static_rtti: absolutely, because the `\x00` bytes won't be accepted. The bytes **must** be ASCII only, and fit the `float()` string interpretation rules.